# Compare Data within List with every other Index

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, list

```
  class A
    {
     public DateTime start;
     public DateTime end;
    }
```

Hi I have a List of A objects of any size and I want to compare each object with other objects in the list if they overlap, My Idea would be to go foreach and run through each object and compare it with whole list. That would be very slow and resource hogging. Anything better?

Comment: I am just looking for the idea to implement the logic

Comment: In which language? And please show us what you have attempted so far. There are a million ways to do this. What have you thought of doing?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I don't get it. To me it seems to be a completely viable question.

Comment: You can solve your problem with [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). But I think that a simpler approach is possible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linearithmic (O(NlogN)) solution would be to sort your objects by startpoint and simply compare the startpoint of every object with the endpoint of the one before it. If the startpoint of object k is lower than or equal to the endpoint of object k-1, then you have overlap. Otherwise, you don't.

I'm not sure about C# but in Java you could do this by implementing the Comparable interface and using Arrays.sort(). I'd wrote you some example code but I'm on mobile.

Comment: and if the start point and endpoint are lower than that of the previous?